# Delayed Queued job fires immediately with database driver

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use Queues in Laravel with a delay. I could never get the delay to work, all the jobs are fired immediately.

I set up the driver as "database" in both config/queue.php and .env
I also created the job table with php artisan and migrated.
Running php artisan queue:work or queue:listen has the same effects, jobs fire instantly.

I see in my database that in the jobs table, the fields "available_at" and "created_at" actually both contain the same timestamp, ignoring the delay I put in the code:

```
$job = (new ParkingMatchJob($this->seller,$this->job_counter+1))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(20));
$this->dispatch($job);
```

I also tried:

```
$job = (new ParkingMatchJob($this->seller,$this->job_counter+1))->delay(20);
$this->dispatch($job);
```

to no avail.

I do not see any error in laravel.log or php_error.log

I thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: Did you implement the `ShouldQueue` interface in your class `ParkingMatchJob`?

Comment: class ParkingMatchJob implements ShouldQueue

Comment: use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

Comment: Have you tried just using the helper dispatch function? Not sure if this will fix the issue, but can you try removing `$this->dispatch($job)` and instead try `dispatch($job)`;

Comment: Are you using the `Illuminate\Bus\Queueable` trait?

Comment: no change in behaviour without just `dispatch($job);`

Comment: yes: `use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;`

Comment: What version of laravel is this?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.4.23

Comment: How do you run your queue worker?

Comment: `php artisan queue:work database`. But I doubt it is because of the worker, it is processing the job when available. The problem is that it is marked as available at the same time it is created in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think dispatch is not in the right order.

It should be before delay():

```
ParkingMatchJob::dispatch($this->seller,$this->job_counter+1)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(20));
```